# iptable rules for double chain vpn

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, openvpn

I want to setup multi chain vpn using openvpn. The idea is as the following

### Client ------- > VPS1 ------------ VPS2 --------- Internet

[image]

I have the following setup:

Windows PC Client

**VPS1** Debian: Openvpn installed with `10.8.0.0/24` with public IP `aa.bb.cc.dd`

**VPS2** Debian: Openvpn installed with `10.7.0.0/24` with public IP `ee.ff.gg.hh`

I tested the connection between **VPS1**-----> **VPS2** and it's working fine. I do `curl ifconfig.me` and I get **VPS2** public IP.

I have the following problem:

1. If I establish connection between **VPS1** and **VPS2**, my ssh connection to **VPS1** get disconnected and also client cannot establish vpn connection to **VPS1**
2. I want **SERVER1** only forward the traffic of vpn clients `10.8.0.0/24`, not all vps traffic.

I do research and I tried many solutions but not working, I don't know how to make **SERVER1** forward vpn traffic to **SERVER2**.

Please help.